# Display loading image after clicking on a image/button using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have developed an App using PhoneGap and JqueryMobile.
I have many HTML Pages , navigation from One page to other page on click of the image is taking lot of time.And the end user have no clue what is happening at the back end.
I would like to show loading image until the page gets loaded.

I'm wondering how could I use Jquery to show a simple "Loading..." on the screen until page is loaded.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

With jquerymobile you can do this with `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` resp. `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()` as described in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html).

Comment: Image tag: `<img src='images/arrow_rightnew.png' class='show-page-loading-msg' onclick='clickedmsgId("+$(this).find('messageId').text()+");'>`
Onclick function:
`function clickedmsgId(msgId){
 $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }`
When I used this, it is showing me the loading image but its not rotating, its just looks like C symbol not showing the loading image.

Comment: Hm, that's strange -- the rotating image is an animated gif, so it should rotate just by it's own. Does this happen within Phonegap? Does it work if you run the web-app in a desktop browser?

Comment: A Mobile App written in HTML/Javascript is still a Web App -- just aimed for browsers on mobile devices. But you can still open it in a desktop-browser :-)

Comment: Not able to make out as its too fast in browser...:(((